# App crashes when navigating to tableView from a xib

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, xib

I'm struggling to find an answer and thought I'll try and ask here.

I have an app that uses UITableView controllers inside a navigationController. The tableView has 2 cells with a custom class and the cells themselves are created in storyBoard.
The cells just have a label and some minor visual tweaks.

In addition, there is also a sort of drawer style expandable tableView on the main page that's created as a xib file. Both - the main tableView and the xib one lead to the last screen when a cell is pressed and use the address shown in the cell to show more detailed info in the final tableView.

When I navigate to the final UITableView from the UITableViewController, everything works perfectly and all the info is showing up nicely inside the cell, as well as the labels within the cells.

Now a problem arises when I try to navigate to the same final tableViewController from the xib.
At first, the app just crashed and I got an error saying that I need to ***register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard.***
When I try to register the nib, I'll get the following error ***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[< NSObject 0x600001ad9f30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key handle.'***
Looks like I'm entering the wrong key for the nibName, but I'm not really sure what else to enter there besides the name of the xib file.

**EDIT:**
Thanks everybody, the error with the handle was a completely separate little mix up that I fixed now but the main problem still persists.
I've added some more explanations and information in the bottom of the post.

I also tried registering the cell with `tableView.register(<cellClass: AnyClass?>, forCellReuseIdentifier: <String>)`
And that fixed the problem of the app crashing but now the tableView cell does not seem to recognize the label inside.

I'm guessing when I register the cell, I also need to let it know somehow about the label inside, but haven't been able to find out how to do it yet.

[Without registering the cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88D0k.png)

[With cell registered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ccs6.png)

**Final tableViewController that should show all the details including the detailLabel with tag**

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      if indexPath.row == 0 {

         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailCell", for: indexPath)
         cell.textLabel?.text = "\(walletData.rowTitles[indexPath.section])"

         if let detailLabel = cell.viewWithTag(125) as? UILabel {

            switch indexPath.section {
            case 0:
               detailLabel.text = walletData.address
            case 1:
               detailLabel.text = "\(walletData.totalMNs)"
            case 2:
               detailLabel.text = walletData.totalShares
            case 3:
               detailLabel.text = "\(walletData.tiers[0].masterNodes.count)"
            case 4:
               detailLabel.text = "\(walletData.tiers[1].masterNodes.count)"
            case 5:
               detailLabel.text = "\(walletData.tiers[2].masterNodes.count)"
            case 6:
               detailLabel.text = "\(walletData.tiers[3].masterNodes.count)"
            default:
               detailLabel.text = "Sumtin' done messed up!"
            }
         }
         return cell
      } else {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mnCell", for: indexPath)
         if let addressLabel = cell.viewWithTag(125) as? UILabel {
            let masterNode = walletData.tiers[indexPath.section - 3].masterNodes[indexPath.row - 1]
            addressLabel.text = masterNode.address
            switch masterNode.state {
            case 1:
               addressLabel.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2196078449, green: 0.007843137719, blue: 0.8549019694, alpha: 1) // Initialize
            case 2:
               addressLabel.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411793, green: 0.6862745285, blue: 0.1333333403, alpha: 1) // Deposited
            case 3:
               addressLabel.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2745098174, green: 0.4862745106, blue: 0.1411764771, alpha: 1) // Active
            case 4:
               addressLabel.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1) // Terminate
            default:
               addressLabel.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9254902005, green: 0.2352941185, blue: 0.1019607857, alpha: 1) // Unknown
            }
         }

         cell.textLabel?.text = walletData.tiers[indexPath.section - 3].masterNodes[indexPath.row - 1].shares
         cell.textLabel?.alpha = 0.75
         cell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.921431005, green: 0.9214526415, blue: 0.9214410186, alpha: 1)
         cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 14)

         return cell
      }
   }
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks everybody for the answers. I had a little hiccup when I was testing different options and forgot I had the **handle** outlet in the code, hence why I didn't recognize the error. But anyway, that was unrelated to the error where my app crashes when navigating from the xib to the final UITableView.

I've added few more pictures to give a bit better idea what exactly goes on and how the navigation inside the app works.

Here you can see the main storyboard and some of the segues.

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyCqq.png)

When pressing on the information indicator on the **Address List Table View Controller** this piece of code gets run and the user is taken to the **Detail Table View Controller** you can see in the bottom right.

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
      if let selectedWallet = groupedWallets[indexPath.section].wallets[indexPath.row].address {
         walletData?.fetchWalletData(address: selectedWallet)

         DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
            if let detailTableViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detailTableViewController") as? DetailTableViewController {
               detailTableViewController.walletData = self.walletData!
               self.show(detailTableViewController, sender: self)
               SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Here you can now see the xib file which is essentially just a UITableView with a little handle are to pull it open

[UITableView xib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maac4.png)

And here is the main page of the app with the xib UITableView opened up.

[UITableView xib in running app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doVxv.png)

Here you will see the code for the **SavedListViewController** which is the owner of the xib file.

```swift
class SavedListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

   let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
   let addressListVC = AddressListTableViewController()
   var selectedWallet = ""
   var savedWallets = [String]()
   var walletData = WalletData()
   let detailTableViewController = DetailTableViewController()

   @IBOutlet var handleArea: UIView!
   @IBOutlet var handle: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


   override func viewDidLoad() {
      guard let walletList = defaults.object(forKey: "savedWallets") as? [String] else { return }
      savedWallets = walletList

      //tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "SavedListView", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "detailCell")
      //tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "SavedListView", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "mnCell")

      view.layer.cornerRadius = 12
      handle.layer.cornerRadius = 6
      handleArea.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.921431005, green: 0.9214526415, blue: 0.9214410186, alpha: 1)
      handleArea.alpha = 0.90
      handle.alpha = 0.90
      view.backgroundColor = .clear
   }


   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return savedWallets.count
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "defaultCell")
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "defaultCell", for: indexPath)
      if savedWallets.isEmpty {
         cell.textLabel?.text = "No addresses saved yet"
      } else {
         cell.textLabel?.text = savedWallets[indexPath.row]
      }
      return cell
   }


   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      selectedWallet = savedWallets[indexPath.row]
      walletData.fetchWalletData(address: selectedWallet)
      detailTableViewController.walletData = walletData
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
         self.show(self.detailTableViewController, sender: self)
         SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
      }
   }  
}
```

So, just to clarify that the UITableView which is created in the xib file shows up nicely. That is the first thing I see when I open the app and everything is in the right place and works.
The crashing happens when I tap on the cell and the didSelectRowAt method gets called.
The method itself looks like that

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      selectedWallet = savedWallets[indexPath.row]
      walletData.fetchWalletData(address: selectedWallet)
      detailTableViewController.walletData = walletData
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
         self.show(self.detailTableViewController, sender: self)
         SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
      }
   }
```

That method now shows the **detailTableViewController** which is again the bottom right one on the storyboard image.
The view shows up but as soon the `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailCell", for: indexPath)` line gets called it crashes.
What really confuses me is that when I access the same VC by tapping on the row within *Address List Table View Controller**, everything works.
But when I tap the row in the **SavedListViewController** I will get the error **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier detailCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'**

Comment: Did you create a separate XIB file for the cells? Generally what can be done is embed the tableview controller in your Navigation controller and then create the prototype cells in the view. If you are not doing that, then you should define a class which extends UITableViewCell and then connect it with the storyboard

Comment: welcome new user - BTW it's perfectly OK to put images right in the question.  (Edit and literally just drag them in)

Comment: Can you share your xib classes?Also try to reconnect the handle reference.

Comment: Thanks Fattie, apparently I'm too much of a n00b to use that privilege yet. Looks like I need at least 10 reputation points to add images directly.

@NickStefanidis, I added the whole xib class to the post above. And cleared up the mess with the "handle" outlet.

Comment: @Henc You have an `imageView` called `handle`, but I can't see it in your storyboard. Did you delete the `imageView` and forgot the name?

Comment: @NickStefanidis, that UIIMageView is in the xib file. If you look at the UITableViewXib image I posted, you can see the small gray imageView that represents the handlebar for dragging open the card view.

Comment: @Henc Try this `tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "SavedListView", bundle: nil) , forCellReuseIdentifier: "detailCell")` without the `init`.

Comment: @NickStefanidis gave it a go but no luck.
I might need to find another way to implement that card view for now and then get bit more familiar with the xib files and come back to this problem here in a month or two.
Appreciate your help though!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance you are connecting the outlets wrong? When in a xib with a UITableViewCell, you must connect the outlets from your class's name, instead of from File's Owner:

1. Keep the File's Owners outlets clear:

[image: Notice the outlets]

2. Connect the outlets to the class:

[image: Outlets connected to the class name]

Answer (score 0):

check your view controller's outlets whether they are connected properly or not.I guess there is an outlet named "handle" in your current VC or the cell you created but it is not linked properly or may be you deleted your view from main story board but its outlet was there in view controller.